# How to see logs during a job execution in jenkins's blue ocean

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I have a weird behaviour in Jenkins(2.46.3LTS) blue ocean gui (1.1.2). 
I don't have the output of my pipeline script (eg. echo "test" ). I only have this output : "Queued Waiting for run to start" despite I have some outputs in the legacy view.

During the job I took two screenshots

[image: Screenshot with legacy gui]

[image: Screenshot with blue ocean]

How can I fix that ?

Comment: did you find out why? I'm encountering this issue now too, it had just worked correctly before but now

Comment: Now I don't really use blue ocean ( too heavy)

Comment: Actually, now it works. I remove the input step from the node . Maybe it helped me .

Comment: We are seeing the same issue in builds that are running with our pipeline (https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline). Insights are very appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the inheritance plugin. https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-66053